# How can I show and hide the textfield type number depending on which radio button was clicked?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I set that once the radio button for paypal was clicked, the textfield type number will be displayed, then, if it wasn't clicked, it will stay hidden?

Also, once COD is clicked, it will show a message like "cod is chosen for the payment option"

```
const page = () => {
      const [payment, setPayment] = useState();
      return (
        <div>
          <Container fixed>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <Typography align="left" variant="subtitle1" color="secondary">
                    Choose Payment Option
                  </Typography>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    value="cod"
                    name="paymentMethod"
                    onChange={(e) => setPayment(e.target.value)}
                  />
                  COD(Cash-on-Delivery)<br></br>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    value="paypal"
                    name="paymentMethod"
                    onChange={(e) => setPayment(e.target.value)}
                  />{" "}
                  Gcash
                  <TextField
                    id="gcash-num"
                    label="paypal"
                    type="number"
                    fullWidth
                  />
                    <Button type="submit">Place an Order</Button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this into your jsx:

```
{ 
  payment === "paypal" && 
    <TextField
      id="gcash-num"
      label="paypal"
      type="number"
      fullWidth
    /> 
}

{
  payment === "cod" &&
    <p>cod is chosen for the payment option</p>
}
```